# MS Access search for record by textbox instead of dropdown

Tags: ms-access

I'm pretty new to MS Access. I'm trying to create a simple form that will basically search for a particular record using a textbox, rather than a drop down box. Essentially a user would be able to enter an ID number and retrieve some other related Info. However, I do not want the user to be able to add any new records to the database. I've been able to get the forms to look the way I want them, but I'm not sure where to place the code (do I create a macro, insert the code into the properties of the button?) Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

I assume that you have bound your form to a table or a query and that you want to be able to enter the ID manually in a textbox, then press ENTER and load that record's data or display an error message if there is no such record.

As [dsteele](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924101/ms-access-search-for-record-by-textbox-instead-of-dropdown/924183#924183) said, make sure that the form's Data property *Allow Addtions* is set to `No` to disallow users from adding records.

Then, from the `AfterUpdate` event of the textbox, add the following code (assuming that your textbox is named `txtGoTo`):

```
Private Sub txtGoTo_AfterUpdate()
    If (txtGoTo & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    Dim rs As DAO.RecordSet
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID]=" & txtGoTo
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & txtGoTo & "' was found.", _
               vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Else
        Me.RecordSet.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
    rs.Close
    txtGoTo = Null
End Sub
```

Note that you will have to change the line `rs.FindFirst "[ID]=" & txtGoTo` to something that is adequate for your data:

- `"[ID]="` should be replaced by the field you want to search (it could be `"[POReference]="` or something else.
- if you are searching by a numeric ID, for instance because the field is an autonumber column, then the code is fine.
  Otherwise, if the field you are searching on is a string (say `PN12-G`) then you have to change the code to:

  ```
  rs.FindFirst "[ID]=""" & txtGoTo & """"
  ```

Failing to use the proper quoting (or quoting where not necessary) will result in errors of the kind *Data type mismatch...*.

As a new user, I would recommend that you have a look at the sample *NorthWind* project database that is either shiped with older versions of Access or available as a template for download from Access 2007.
There a lots of techniques to learn from as a new Access developer, including other ways to implement record navigation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the form property Data/'Allow Additions' to No.
2. Either in the AfterUpdate event of the textbox, or in the Click event of a button, you can write code or assign a macro to look up and display the record you want.