# Find record with ID

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to move to a record that has a certain ID.

I tried the solution on this post: [MS Access search for record by textbox instead of dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924101/ms-access-search-for-record-by-textbox-instead-of-dropdown)

but no success

Here's my code

```
Private Sub btnShowPrevious_Click()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID]=" & ParentID
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & ParentID & "' was found.", _
               vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Else
        Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

It always hit no match but parentID = 1 and there's one record with ID = 1..

Anyone has an idea of what is wrong?

Thank you

The record source is this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProposalFollowUp](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ProposalID] [int] NOT NULL,
[MillID] [int] NULL,
[ClientID] [int] NULL,
[Comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Method] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
[Contact] [int] NULL,
[ContactDate] [datetime] NULL,
[Done] [bit] NOT NULL,
[CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
[EAIEmployee] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[PersonInCharge] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ParentID] [int] NULL,
```

here's a screenshot of the form properties

[image]

Finaly, if I show the navigation bar, I can see there's a filter.
Probably because I open the form like this

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "ProposalsFollowUp", , , "[ID] = " & txtID, acFormEdit, acDialog
```

If I remove the filter, it works.

Alright
Here's the final code

```
Private Sub btnShowPrevious_Click()
    Dim parent As Integer
    parent = ParentID
    Me.Filter = ""
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID]=" & parent
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & parent & "' was found.", _
               vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Else
        Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, the question is updated now

Comment: Your sample code works for me with a linked SQL Server table. How have you connected the table and what is the recordsource  property of the form? Have you any filters?

Comment: There's no filter and I have linked SQL Server tables :( I updated a screenshot of form properties

Comment: What happens when you manually find a record (click in the parent ID box and choose find in the menu) ? What happens if you substitute a value `rs.FindFirst "[ID]=1"`

Comment: I tried to find, no result. If I apply a filter on parentID=1 it brings me to a new record. All the fields are empty. Also `rs.FindFirst "[ID]=1"` equals no match.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17133/discussion-between-remou-and-marc)

Comment: Finaly I had a filter so I fixed it by clearing the filter like this `Me.Filter = "";`  You can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking everything obvious such as ensuring the recordset includes the data you are searching for and that there are no filters, you can consider a problem with the form. A filter is shown at the bottom of the form in Access 2010 and can be removed in VBA by:

```
Me.FilterOn = False
```

Or by clicking the filter button:

[image: form filter access 2010]

Odd things happening in a front-end are often due to corruption of some sort. You need to  regularly back-up, compact and repair and decompile when you are developing. If you have linked tables, it is often a good idea to refresh the links.

If you create a form you do not want to lose and it becomes corrupt, you can copy to a new form with cut and paste or you can export to text and import.

Decompile:

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft office\office\msaccess.exe" /decompile "c:\My Documents\MyDatabase.mdb"
```

-- http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html

Save As Text:

```
Application.SaveAsText acForm, "FormName", "z:\docs\tmp.txt"
Application.LoadFromText acForm, "restoredForm", "z:\docs\tmp.txt"
```